# Arduino Ethernet shield slow to connect with android app

Tags: android, apache, http, arduino

So I've created a webserver that outputs the values from a couple of analogue sensors when a command is received from an android app. However it lags whenever any button is pressed and only occasionally works, usually crashing the app. This is the arduino code:

```
//ARDUINO 1.0+ ONLY                                                            
//ARDUINO 1.0+ ONLY                                                            


#include <Ethernet.h>                                                          
#include <SPI.h>                                                               
// the value of the 'other' resistor                                           
#define SERIESRESISTOR 10000                                            

// What pin to connect the sensor to                                           
#define THERMISTORPIN A0                                                      
boolean reading = false;                                                       
const int analogInPin = A1;                                                    
int sensorValue = 0;                                                           

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////       
//CONFIGURE                                                                    
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////       
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 0, 101 };   //Manual setup only                        
byte gateway[] = { 192, 168, 0, 1 }; //Manual setup only                       
byte subnet[] = { 255, 255, 255, 0 }; //Manual setup only                      

// if need to change the MAC address (Very Rare)                               
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };                           

EthernetServer server = EthernetServer(80); //port 80                          
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////       

void setup(){                                                                  
    Serial.begin(9600);                                                        

    //Pins 10,11,12 & 13 are used by the ethernet shield                       

    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);                                                        



    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet); //for manual setup               

    server.begin();                                                            
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());                                        

}                                                                              

void loop(){                                                                   

    // listen for incoming clients, and process qequest.                       
    checkForClient();                                                          

    tempReading();                                                             

} 

void tempReading(){                                                            
    sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);                                  
    EthernetClient client2 = server.available();                               
    if (client2) {                                                             

        // an http request ends with a blank line                              
        boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;                                     
        boolean sentHeader = false;                                            

        while (client2.connected()) {                                          

            if (client2.available()) {                                         

                if(!sentHeader){                                               
                    // send a standard http response header                    
                    client2.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");                        
                    client2.println("Content-Type: text/html");                
                    client2.println();                                         
                    sentHeader = true;                                         
                }                                                              

                float reading;                                                 

                reading = analogRead(THERMISTORPIN);                           

                Serial.print("Analog reading ");-                              
                Serial.println(reading);                                       

                // convert the value to resistance                             
                reading = (1023 / reading)  - 1;                               
                reading = SERIESRESISTOR / reading;                            
                Serial.print("Thermistor resistance ");                   
                Serial.println(reading);                                       


                delay(1000);                                                   
                float reading2;                                                
                char d = client2.read();                                       

                if(reading2 && d == ' ') reading2 = false;                     
                if(d == '?') reading2 = true; //found the ?, begin reading the info 

                if(reading2){                                                  


                    switch (d) {                                               
                      case '4':                                                
                        //add code here to trigger on 2                        
                        client2.print("Thermistor resistance: ");              
                        client2.println(reading);                              
                        client2.println("\n");                                 
                        break;                                                 
                      case '5':                                                
                        client2.print("Light Level: ");                        
                        client2.println(sensorValue);                          
                        client2.println("\n");                                 
                    }                                                          
                }                                                              

            }                                                                  

        }                                                                      
        delay(1); // give the web browser time to receive the data             
        client2.stop(); // close the connection:                               

    }                                                                          
}                                                                              



void checkForClient(){                                                         

    EthernetClient client = server.available();                                

    if (client) {                                                              

        // an http request ends with a blank line                              
        boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;                                     
        boolean sentHeader = false;                                            

        while (client.connected()) {                                           

            if (client.available()) {                                          

                if(!sentHeader){                                               
                    // send a standard http response header                    
                    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");                         
                    client.println("Content-Type: text/html");                 
                    client.println();                                          
                    sentHeader = true;                                         
                }                                                              

                char c = client.read();                                        

                if(reading && c == ' ') reading = false;                       
                if(c == '?') reading = true; //found the ?, begin reading the info 

                if(reading){                                                   
                    Serial.print(c);                                           

                    switch (c) {                                               
                      case '1':                                                
                        //add code here to trigger on 2                        
                        pinOn(7, client);                                      
                        break;                                                 
                      case '2':                                                
                        //add code here to trigger on 3                        
                        pinOff(7, client);                                     
                        break;                                                 


                    }                                                          

                }                                                              

                if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank)  break;                   

                if (c == '\n') {                                               
                    currentLineIsBlank = true;                                 
                }else if (c != '\r') {                                         
                    currentLineIsBlank = false;                                
                }                                                              

            }                                                                  
        }                                                                      

        delay(1); // give the web browser time to receive the data             
        client.stop(); // close the connection:                                

    }
          void pinOff(int pin, EthernetClient client){                                   


    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);                                                   

}                                                                              
void pinOn(int pin, EthernetClient client){                                    

    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);                                                    

}
```

and this is the Android code:

```
package com.example.liam.arduinocontroller;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;


public class ControlClass extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
                ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_control_class);
        View led1on = findViewById(R.id.led_1on);
        View led1off = findViewById(R.id.led_1off);
        View led2on = findViewById(R.id.led_2on);
        View led2off = findViewById(R.id.led_2off);

        led1on.setOnClickListener(this);
        led1off.setOnClickListener(this);
        led2on.setOnClickListener(this);
        led2off.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void commandArduino(String url) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpParams httpParameters = httpclient.getParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);
            httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_control_class, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View thisView) {



            switch(thisView.getId())


            {
                case R.id.led_1on:
                    commandArduino("http://192.168.0.101/?2");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "led_1on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.led_1off:
                    commandArduino("http://192.168.0.101/?3");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "led_1off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.led_2on:
                    commandArduino("http://192.168.0.101/?4");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TempDisplay.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.led_2off:
                    commandArduino("http://192.168.0.101/?5");
                    Intent j = new Intent(this, LightDisplay.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
            }




    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The main issue is the two parser. You need one request parser, dispatching base on the read request

Answer (score 0):

I try to refactor your code

```
//ARDUINO 1.0+ ONLY 

#include <Ethernet.h> 
#include <SPI.h> 
// the value of the 'other' resistor 
#define SERIESRESISTOR 10000 

// What pin to connect the sensor to 
#define THERMISTORPIN A0 
const int analogInPin = A1; 

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
//CONFIGURE 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 0, 101 };   //Manual setup only 
byte gateway[] = { 192, 168, 0, 1 }; //Manual setup only 
byte subnet[] = { 255, 255, 255, 0 }; //Manual setup only 

// if need to change the MAC address (Very Rare) 
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED }; 

EthernetServer server = EthernetServer(80); //port 80 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

void setup(){ 
    Serial.begin(9600); 

    //Pins 10,11,12 & 13 are used by the ethernet shield 

    pinMode(7, OUTPUT); 

    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet); //for manual setup 
    server.begin(); 
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP()); 
} 

void loop() { 
    boolean reading = false;    
    EthernetClient client = server.available(); 

    if (client) { 
        // an http request ends with a blank line 
        boolean currentLineIsBlank = true; 
        boolean sentHeader = false; 

        while (client.connected()) { 
            if (client.available()) { 
                if (!sentHeader){ 
                    // send a standard http response header 
                    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); 
                    client.println("Content-Type: text/html"); 
                    client.println(); 
                    sentHeader = true; 
                } 

                char c = client.read(); 
                if (reading && c == ' ') { 
                    reading = false; 
                } 
                if (c == '?') { 
                    //found the ?, begin reading the info 
                    reading = true; 
                } 

                if (reading){ 
                    Serial.print(c); 
                    switch (c) { 
                      case '1': 
                        pinOn(7, client); 
                        break; 
                      case '2': 
                        pinOff(7, client); 
                        break; 
                      case '4': 
                        print_thermistor(&client); 
                        break; 

                      case '5': 
                        print_light(&client); 
                        break; 
                    } 
                } 

                if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) 
                    break; 
                if (c == '\n') { 
                    currentLineIsBlank = true; 
                } else if (c != '\r') { 
                    currentLineIsBlank = false; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        delay(500); // give the web browser time to receive the data 
        client.stop(); // close the connection: 
    } 
}

void print_thermistor(EthernetClient *client) { 
    float th; 

    th = analogRead(THERMISTORPIN); 

    Serial.print("Analog th "); 
    Serial.println(th); 

    // convert the value to resistance 
    th = (1023 / th)  - 1; 
    th = SERIESRESISTOR / th; 
    Serial.print("Thermistor resistance "); 
    Serial.println(th); 

    client->print("Thermistor resistance: "); 
    client->println(th); 
    client->println("\n"); 
} 

void print_light(EthernetClient *client) { 
    int sensorValue; 

    sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin); 
    client->print("Light Level: "); 
    client->println(sensorValue); 
    client->println("\n"); 
} 

void pinOff(int pin, EthernetClient client){ 
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH); 

} 
void pinOn(int pin, EthernetClient client){ 
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW); 
}
```